# Exclude aspx files from search results in SharePoint Foundation 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search-results, aspx

If possible, how can I exclude `aspx` files from search results in SharePoint Foundation 2010 (+ without Search Server Express) ?

Answer (score 0):

Without Search Server Express there may not be a lot you can do.  With Search Server Express you could manage this in a scope definition.

You could try this (...not 100% it will do what you want):

**Site Settings** > **Site Administration** > **Search and offline availability**

Set **Index ASPX Page Content** to **Never index any Web Parts on this site**.